# Python - Increasing performance speed of permutation calculation of Itertools; repeat=15

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, permutation, python-itertools

What methods of increasing calculation when repeat is greater then 15 using itertools?

**permutation.py**

```
#import string

inputRepeat = input('>>> Enter repeat value. (int): ')
L = string.ascii_uppercase

i = list(''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(L, repeat=inputRepeat))
print i
```

When repeat becomes larger, the code is storing/computing into memory before output in some fashion. Methods of optimized version with memory management solutions.

Share your thoughts!

Comment: I think this is intrinsic to the problem. I'm surprised you don't run out of memory at repeat=15!

Comment: Aside: what do you have against the letter X?  (If you meant to include all uppercase letters, you should use `string.ascii_uppercase` instead, to avoid problems like this.)

Comment: I did some research from other users when repeat is larger, and I collected that it's not the code; from the current perspective, it's valid. Are there methods that I could use to iterate in portions, such as X permutations at a time, and then continue once complete to the next amount?

Comment: You are trying to make a list of over a thousand billion billion things. This will never work; the solution is to find a non-brute-force way to do whatever you're trying to use this list for.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that was a possible concern. I figured I could use matrix and list combinations to generate permutations of the same result, and using a matching algorithm to perform matching. I figured that we could combine elements that would result in unique permutations.

Comment: ```such as X permutations at a time``` : sounds like you are coming up with ideas, you should explore them and probably give some thought to @user2357112 's comment.

Answer (score 1):

depending on how you are using the elements of the list, you do not need to keep them in memory. that's what `itertools` does for you

```
import string
import itertools

inputRepeat = input('>>> Enter repeat value. (int): ')
L = string.ascii_uppercase

#i = list(''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(L, repeat=int(inputRepeat)))
#print(i)

for rep in itertools.product(L, repeat=int(inputRepeat)):
    print(''.join(rep))
```

but the complexity of the problem stays...